# server side splitting/cropping video files

Tags: video, server-side, crop

I am working on a project where we need to essentially take a single video and split it into two videos by simply cutting the captured video in half.  for example, if the video resolution was 640 x 320, it would turn into two files each 320 x 320. Assuming this was accomplished on the server-side (preferably), what program can be used?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can run a `shell_exec` to FFmpeg to encode your videos.